# Getting syntex error while executing procedure in informix 12.10

Tags: procedure, informix

I'm trying to create a procedure with 2 input parameters in Informix 12.10. I want to insert the time filtered results in a table. but when I execute this code I'm getting a syntax error.

```
create dba procedure informix.damper_count (from_date nvarchar(25),to_date nvarchar(25))
 
   begin 
    delete damper_count_temp
    insert into  damper_count_temp (station,device,event,count)
    select * 
    from (select 'SWA' ,'TVD 01' ,'Damper Close' ,count(cmrl_desccol ) from "informix".alarms
        where desccol LIKE '%%SWA_TVD_1 - Damper Close%' and LocalCol between from_date and to_date
        union
        select 'SWA' ,'TVD 01' ,'Damper Open' ,count(cmrl_desccol ) from "informix".alarms 
        where desccol LIKE '%%SWA_TVD_1 - Damper Open%' and LocalCol between from_date and to_date   )                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   end
end procedure;
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **;** at the end of the delete, insert and select statements within the procedure.
Not sure you need a begin/end